# About using "whosever"

Tags: word-usage

The following are my understanding about using "whosever." Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you.

---

❶ Whosever answer, if correct, comes out first gets the prize.

➜ Correct, and it means anyone whose answer, if correct, comes out first gets the prize.

---

❷ Whosever proposal promises the greatest profit will be adopted.

➜ Correct, and it means the proposal, no matter whose (proposal) it is, that promises the greatest profit will be adopted.

---

❸ Whosever number I dialed last night will show up today.

Correct, and it means anyone whose number I dialed last night will show up today.

---

❹ Whosever number I dialed last night has proven wrong.

➜ Correct, and it means the number, no matter whose (number) it was, has proven wrong.

Comment: Can I suggest that you first correct the spelling? It's not clear whether you are referring to **whoever** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whoever or **whosoever** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whosoever

Comment: @JavaLatte He is referring to the possessive "whosever" - which is correctly spelt ( https://www.lexico.com/definition/whosever ).  However, the fact that you did not realise this reflects the fact that "whosever" is a rare word.  People tend to say "whoever's" instead.

Comment: @JavaLatte I'm referring to whosever.

Comment: @rjpond Thank you. I am aware it's rare word. May I ask whether my understanding about the sentences is correct if I replace whosever with whoever's?

Comment: Yes, they are correct. Both the versions with "whosever" and the ones with "whoever's" are correct, but the "whosever" version may feel excessively formal or awkward to some speakers. My only hesitation is about (1), since it will be the respondent who gets the prize, not the answer itself. Also, perhaps "is given" or (depending on context) "is received" or "is opened" would work better than "comes out".

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602701).